# Ruby on Rails paperclip imagemagick error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this has been asked before, but none of the provided solutions seems to work for. I keep gettin this error while I try to upload files with paperclip and imagemagick.

```
Could not run the `identify` command. Please install ImageMagick.
```

I installed imagemagick a few times alreay with

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

I put these in my development.rb. I'm not sure what it means, but I read in in another question here:

```
  Paperclip.options[:image_magick_path] = "/opt/ImageMagick/bin"
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/ImageMagick/bin"
```

This is my model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base


  has_attached_file :file
  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :small => "100x200"}
  validates_attachment :picture, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
```

is there anything else I can do?

Ther eis also an error I get after the installation of imagemagick. I dont know how can I fix it:

```
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  imagemagick-common libilmbase6 liblqr-1-0 libmagickcore5 libmagickwand5
  libopenexr6 libmagickcore5-extra imagemagick libnetpbm10 netpbm
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Y
Err http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main imagemagick-common all 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80]
Err http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main libilmbase6 amd64 1.0.1-6
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80]
Err http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main liblqr-1-0 amd64 0.4.1-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80]
Err http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main libopenexr6 amd64 1.6.1-7
  404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main imagemagick-common all 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main libmagickcore5 amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main libmagickwand5 amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main libmagickcore5-extra amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main imagemagick amd64 8:6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick-common_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/ilmbase/libilmbase6_1.0.1-6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80]
Failed to fetch http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libl/liblqr/liblqr-1-0_0.4.1-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickwand5_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openexr/libopenexr6_1.6.1-7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 193.2.1.88 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagickcore5-extra_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/imagemagick_6.7.7.10-5ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: My guess is either
(a) ImageMagick wasn't properly installed, or 
(b) those paths you put in `development.rb` aren't actually where ImageMagick is installed

Comment: how can i know where imagemagick is installed?

Comment: You are probably right about the installation. I tried again. I included error in my edited question, I have no idea what should I do about it.

Comment: Hmmm. See last line of the stack trace: `Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Comment: i tried, it didn't work

Comment: You could try installing it a different way. Do you use homebrew?  http://brew.sh/
`brew update && brew install imagemagick` may do it

Comment: homebrew is for Mac, but `sudo apt-get` sounds like Ubuntu. You get the correct path with `which indentify`.